# Swift - Sort array element by range

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, sorting, swift3

I'm currently working with the "Charts" pod.

My app shows a bar chart of athletes results, with:

> - X Axis: number of reps / time / rounds / weight
> - Y Axis: number of athletes

I would like to gather the number of reps in different groups.

Something that would be like: 10 < x < 20, 20 < x < 30, etc...
Rather than the real total of reps.

Something like that:
[image]

What would be the best way to do so? I though about some approaches:

- **Round the number of reps** to transform 19 and 15 to 10 and 10 for example (for the 10 < x < 20 category)
  The problem with that method is that I don't know if I can do the same for the "time (seconds)
- **Create a new array with dictionnaries inside**, something like:

  [["10-20": 15, 17, 19], ["20-30": 21, 22, 22, 24], etc..]

But I don't know how to achieve that...

What would be the best way?

Comment: You can group an array to a dictionary with [`Dictionary(grouping:by)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/2995342-init)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Dictionary`'s `init(grouping:by:)` initializer to create such a dictionary:

```
let array = [15,17,19,22,24,24,27]
let dict = Dictionary(grouping: array, by: { $0 / 10 })

// dict is [2: [22, 24, 24, 27], 1: [15, 17, 19]]
```

If I understood you correctly, you probably have a bunch of `Athlete`s and they have a `reps` property. You can group by `$0.reps / 10` instead:

```
Dictionary(grouping: athletes, by: { $0.reps / 10 })
```

And then map the keys and values to this:

```
.map { ("\($0.key * 10) - \(($0.key + 1) * 10)", $0.value.count) }

// now you have this:
// [("20 - 30", 4), ("10 - 20", 3)]
```

Comment: Awesome! I didn't know that function! Thanks a lot that's perfect!